# Mail::to() solo envía a un usuario de la colección, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

tengo el siguiente problema con **Laravel**:

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electrónico, masivo, mediante la **Facade** `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail` de **Laravel** con el siguiente código en mi **controlador**:

```php
$users = User::select(['name', 'email'])
   ->get();

// $validator solo es una Array con los datos de la Request una vez validados
Mail::to($users)->send(new MassiveMail($validator['subject'], $validator['title'], $validator['body']));
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi **clase** `MassiveMail`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

// Pueden ver que se despachan en la cola de trabajos, por defecto
class MassiveMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subjectMessage;
    public $title;
    public $body;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $title, $body)
    {
        $this->subjectMessage = $subject;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subjectMessage)
        ->view('emails.massive', [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body
        ]);
    }
}
```

Lo que sucede es que al enviar el correo solo se le envía a un usuario de la **Collection**, el cual supongo es el primero, de 20 usuarios a los que debería enviarse.

Todos estos usuarios son creados con **Faker** por lo cual sus **emails** no son reales, así que tengo configurado el desvió en de los correos a una sola dirección *(La mía)*; en mi `config/mail.php`:

```php
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        //....
    ],

    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'micorreo@ejemplo.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME', 'Usuario'),
    ],
```

Entonces, no se si la verdad esto es lo que me esta causando este problema y de ser así funcionaria con normalidad una vez estando en **producción**, pero por ahora no tengo como probarlo.

Intente pasar la **collection** a un **Array asociativo** pero esto tampoco funciono, seguía enviándose a un solo destinatario. Lo único que funciono para mi fue iterar la **collection** con un `foreach` así:

```php
foreach($users as $user)
{
    Mail::to($user)->send(new MassiveMail($validator['subject'], $validator['title'], $validator['body']));
}
```

Pero claro que esto aumenta potencialmente el tiempo de respuesta de la aplicación, a pesar de que los despacha en una **cola de trabajos** y no es lo ideal. Espero puedan ayudarme con esto o aclarar mi inquietud.

Mil gracias de antemano, un saludo

Comment: Quita el desvío que tienes a tu cuenta y prueba el servicio mailtrap.io, captura todos los correos en una bandeja y para desarrollar viene bien. Y así vemos si es por mandarlos todos a la misma cuenta

Comment: @j0se si probare eso, aunque por una razón que olvide mencionar, dudo que sea eso, y es que cuando envió correos con una notificación `\Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage` a varios usuarios, si me llega la cantidad esperada de correos. De igual forma probare y colocare el resultado